# deduce template argument for typedef'd function pointer

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers, typedef

Is there a way to deduce a template argument for a function pointer when using a typedef?  My sample code is:

```
struct A {};
void func(const A&) {};

template <typename T>
struct FuncPtr
{
    typedef void(*Type)(const T&);
};

void f_(FuncPtr<A>::Type) {}

template <typename T> // I'd like to hide the messy function pointer in a typedef
void f1(typename FuncPtr<T>::Type fp) { f_(fp); }

template <typename T> // this works, but "fp" is really several lines long
void f2(void(*fp)(const T&)) { f_(fp); }
```

With that in place, I can call `f2(AFunc)`.  But I'd rather have something closer to `f1(func)` because in my actual code the declaration for the function pointer is much longer.  And I need to have an actual function pointer, rather than just passing a template argument, so that I can call `f_()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not with your current setup. Everything to the left of `::`<sup>*</sup> is a non-deduced context, because a metafunction can apply arbitrary Turing-complete transformations on the type, and in any event there's no guaranteed one-to-one mapping between the original type and the result. So the language doesn't even try.

But an alias template will work:

```
template <class T>
using FuncPtr = void (*)(const T&);

template <typename T>
void f3(FuncPtr<T> fp) { return f_(fp); }
```

---

<sub><sup>*</sup>Formally known as the "*nested-name-specifier* of a type that was specified using a *qualified-id*" ([temp.deduct.type]/p5).</sub>

Answer (score 1):

As “Effective Modern C++” Item 9，Prefer alias declarations to typedefs says：

> In particular, alias declarations may be templatized (in which case
>   they’re called alias templates), while typedefs cannot. This gives
>   C++11 programmers a straightforward mechanism for expressing things
>   that in C++98 had to be hacked together with typedefs nested inside
>   templatized structs.For example, consider defining a synonym for a linked list that uses a custom allocator, MyAlloc. With an alias template, it’s a piece of cake:

```
template<typename T
using MyAllocList = std::list<T, MyAlloc<T>>;
MyAllocList<Widget> lw;
```

> With a typedef, you pretty much have to create the cake from
>   scratch:

```
template<typename T> 
struct MyAllocList { 
 typedef std::list<T, MyAlloc<T>> type; 
}; 
MyAllocList<Widget>::type lw;
```